# MS SQL Order By To long execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a problem with sql execution time with Order By.
The problem is if i am doing Order By, it is take a long time and i have a peak on my server. 
If there any way to take a max values without order by

Example of Code with Order By:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 s.title, s.imageUrl, count(sv.saleid) as mostViewPeriod14Days, s.guid 
FROM dbo.Sales s 
INNER JOIN dbo.KEY_BrandcategoryToSale b_key ON s.id = b_key.saleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.SaleView sv ON s.id = sv.saleId 
WHERE (sv.date <= GETDATE()) 
AND (sv.date >= GETDATE() - 14) 
AND s.isActive = 1 AND s.isHotsale = 1 
AND b_key.brandCategoryId = 28 AND s.id NOT IN (SELECT sv.saleId FROM dbo.SaleView sv WHERE sv.userId = 99114) 
GROUP BY s.title, s.imageUrl, s.guid 
ORDER BY mostViewPeriod14Days Desc
```

And what i what is work good but without order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 s.title, s.imageUrl, count(sv.saleid) as mostViewPeriod14Days, s.guid 
    FROM dbo.Sales s 
    INNER JOIN dbo.KEY_BrandcategoryToSale b_key ON s.id = b_key.saleId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.SaleView sv ON s.id = sv.saleId 
    WHERE (sv.date <= GETDATE()) 
    AND (sv.date >= GETDATE() - 14) 
    AND s.isActive = 1 AND s.isHotsale = 1 
    AND b_key.brandCategoryId = 28 AND s.id NOT IN (SELECT sv.saleId FROM dbo.SaleView sv WHERE sv.userId = 99114) 
    GROUP BY s.title, s.imageUrl, s.guid
```

Comment: Just add an index on mostViewPeriod14Days

Comment: Side note: Lose the `DISTINCT`. It is not doing anything here.

Comment: side note : do you hvae an index on SaleView with date, id   - date being the first field.    Does brand category (b_key) have an index on saleid.   I only bring these up if you have not looked at it as a lack of index problem.

Comment: Conceptually, the query is slowing down with the `ORDER BY` because it's having to calculate the number of **SaleView** records for every single **Sales** record. On the first query, it just grabs the first 3 Sales records and calculates the count of **SaleView**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the query below and let me know if it helps. A few general points below

- WHERE clauses that contain a calculated date are slower than those that don't.
- If you can avoid it, never put a "sub-select" in a query. Change that to a left join and check for null records (it's way faster)

  ```
  DECLARE @Today DATETIME; 
  DECLARE @TwoWeeksAgo DATETIME;

  SET @Today = GETDATE();
  SET @TwoWeeksAgo = DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE());

  SELECT TOP 3 
  s.title, 
  s.imageUrl, 
  count(sv.saleid) as mostViewPeriod14Days, 
  s.guid 
  FROM dbo.Sales s 
  INNER JOIN dbo.KEY_BrandcategoryToSale b_key ON s.id = b_key.saleId 
  INNER JOIN dbo.SaleView sv ON s.id = sv.saleId 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.SaleView sv2 on sv2.id = sv.id and sv2.userId = 99114
  WHERE sv.Date BETWEEN @TwoWeeksAgo AND @Today
  AND sv2.id IS NULL     -- This is the check that handles your sub-select earlier
  AND s.isActive = 1 AND s.isHotsale = 1 
  AND b_key.brandCategoryId = 28 
  GROUP BY s.title, s.imageUrl, s.guid 
  ORDER BY mostViewPeriod14Days Desc
  ```